# sed - how to use \b word boundary correctly?

Tags: sed

I want to replace quotes that are at the start of a word.

For example:

```
$ echo "a 'line' a single ' after a  'keyword' with a few space's for a program"\
| sed "s/\b'/X/g"
a 'lineX a single ' after a  'keywordX with a few spaceXs for a program
```

but as you can see they are getting replaced at the **end** of words not the beginning.
How to replace ones that start a word?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This replaces `'` at word beginnings:

```
$ echo "a 'line' a single ' after a  'keyword' with a few space's for a program"| sed "s/'\b/X/g"
a Xline' a single ' after a  Xkeyword' with a few spaceXs for a program
```

For humans, not computers, there is one peculiarity here:  the computer counts `space's` as two words and replaces the `'` because it is at the beginning of the second word.

#### Discussion

`\b` marks a word boundary, either beginning or end.  Now consider `\b'`.  This matches a word boundary followed by a `'`.  Since `'` is *not* a word character, this means that the end of word must precede the `'` to match.  To use `\b` to match at beginnings of words, reverse the order: `'\b`.  Again, since `'` is not a word character, this will only match if a word follows the `'`.

Some seds, like GNU sed, support `\<` to match the beginning of words.  This doesn't help in your case because `'` is already not a word character and that forces the issue.

#### What to do about "space's"

If you don't want the `'` replaced in `space's` because the `'` appears at the end of a word, you can reverse the logic by using `\B`:

```
$ echo "a 'line' a single ' after a  'keyword' with a few space's for a program"| sed "s/\B'/X/g"
a Xline' a single X after a  Xkeyword' with a few space's for a program
```

`\B` matches at *not a word boundary*.  Thus `\B'` matches at `'` (space-quote) because neither space nor quote are word characters.  It does not match at `space'` because `e'` is a word boundary: `e` is a word character and `'` isn't.

Comment: A word boundary is in essence a whitespace?

Comment: @stephanmg A word boundary is not a space.  It is the boundary (or position) __between__ a word character (example: alphanumeric) and a non-word character (examples: space or punctuation).

Comment: Ah yes ok thanks John! That makes sense.